# Getting output many times in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int fav_num {0};
    bool in_range {false};

    while (in_range == false) {
        std::cout << "Enter your favorite number between 1 and 100: ";
        std::cin >> fav_num;

        if (fav_num < 1 || fav_num > 100 || !std::cin ) {
            std::cout << "===Ops!, invalid choice, please try again.===" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Amazing!! That's my favorite number too!" << std::endl; 
            std::cout << "No really!!, " << fav_num << " is my favorite number!" << std::endl;
            in_range = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "==================================================" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting my output many times?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please copy the console output as text into the question, instead of making a screenshot. Screenshots of text are bad for plenty reasons, one being that people who can't see images won't be able to read the text.

Comment: Mathematician's list of prime numbers: 2,3,5,7,11,... Scientist's list: 2,3,5,7,9 (experimental error),... Computer programmer's list: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once for `q`, once for `w`, once for `e`.

Check the docs for [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). Without parameter, it skips only one character, so your loop will go through each character once, before it accepts new input again.

You want `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to ignore every character until the next line.

Comment: Can even make it ezpz with `auto ignore_eol = [](std::istream& in) { in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); };` then one could conveniently do `ignore_eol(std::cin);`

Comment: @Eljay: Or you could make an ordinary function.  No reason to use the complexity of a lambda for such a simple usage.